# Implementing Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network

### Context

I was making a Convolutional Neural Network from scratch in Python. I completed making it .... It works fine ... The only thing is that it takes a lot of time as the size of the input grows.

### Code

```py
import numpy as np
import math

class ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self, num_of_filters, kernel_shape, stride):
        self.num_of_filters = num_of_filters
        self.kernel_shape = kernel_shape
        self.stride = stride
        self.kernels = []

        # Initialize 
        for i in range(self.num_of_filters):
            self.kernel = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=[3,3])
            self.kernels.append(self.kernel)
        self.kernels = np.array(self.kernels)

    def ElementWiseAddition(self, images):
        if np.array(images).shape[0] == 1:
            return images[0]
        
        resultant_image = images[0]
        for image in images[1:]:
            resultant_image = np.add(image, resultant_image)
            resultant_image = resultant_image.astype(float)
            resultant_image /= 2.0

        return resultant_image

    def GetOutput(self, x):
        filter_maps = []
        for filter_n in range(self.num_of_filters):
            kernel_n_filter_maps = []
            for image in x:
                filter_map = []
                for i in range(0, (image.shape[0]-3)+1, self.stride):
                    row = []
                    for j in range(0, (image.shape[1]-3)+1, self.stride):
                        piece = image[i:i+3, j:j+3]
                        value = np.sum(np.multiply(self.kernels[filter_n], piece))

                        # Apply Softmax Activation
                        if value < 0.0:
                            value = 0
                        row.append(value)
                    filter_map.append(row)
                kernel_n_filter_maps.append(filter_map)
            filter_maps.append(self.ElementWiseAddition(kernel_n_filter_maps))
        return np.array(filter_maps)

input = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=[512, 4, 4])

ConvolutionalNN = ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork(1028, [3,3], stride=1)
output = ConvolutionalNN.GetOutput(input)
print(output.shape)
```

How can I make this code consume less time and make it more efficient?

Comment: What does your code do?

Comment: @AryanParekh The code is an implementation of Convolutional Neural Network

Comment: I think what @ayan wants to know is what is the output of the code. I am a newbie myself. I ran your code in spyder and I can't make sense of the massive arrays of numbers.

Comment: Yes @RoniSaiba is correct, it is very unclear as to what your code does, [edit] your question and add more details.

Comment: @AryanParekh sorry but if you are not aware of Convolutional Neural Network, then you cannot understand the question I can't explain what it is in the question as it is a very vast topic

Comment: @RoniSaiba sorry but if you are not aware of Convolutional Neural Network, then you cannot understand the question. I can't explain what it is in the question as it is a very vast topic

Comment: @NITINAGARWAL Yes, I do not understand what convolutional neural networks are. However, to help you, others need to know what you are providing as an input to the network (or code) as well as what is the expected output. It is like saying '5' without saying 'if i provide the input 5 to the function x/5 i get the output 5.'

Comment: @NITINAGARWAL The question lacks a lot of details. Yes, a neural network but what for?

Comment: @AryanParekh It is just a neural network implementation. It can be used for any task you want it for